# How to change date format depends on user locale?

Tags: apex, date, datetime

I want to change date format depends on logged in user locale.

```
Date start_date = 2017-25-11;
```

If user is from China, start_date should display as:

```
2017-25-11
```

If user from US, `start_date` should display as:

```
11/25/2017
```

If user from India, `start_date` should display as:

```
25/11/2017
```

How can I convert `start_date` (date field) dynamically depending on logged in user locale?

Comment: you can use apex:outfield to display the date field. it will automatically convert into current user's locale

Answer (score 9):

There is a [`Date`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm) method for that:

> **format()**
>
> Returns the Date as a string using the locale of the context user

Here are what those formats would look like:

```
LocaleSidKey    toLabel(LocaleSidKey)      Output
=====================================================
zh_CN           Chinese (China)            2017-11-25
en_US           English (United States)    11/25/2017
en_IN           English (India)            25/11/2017
```

Comment: Can I do this same thing in javascript?